# "No matching node is available." error when trying to bootstrap juju

Tags: juju, maas

This is my error while doing bootstrap , the status of nodes I added were declared and now I have accept and commising and it says comminsing started , I need help please ..

```
clusteruser@cluster:~$ juju status
2012-08-04 22:27:03,367 INFO Connecting to environment...
2012-08-04 22:27:04,945 ERROR juju environment not found: is the environment bootstrapped?
clusteruser@cluster:~$ juju bootstrap
2012-08-04 22:27:10,493 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
2012-08-04 22:27:10,923 ERROR No matching node is available.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have nodes that are in the "ready" state before they can be allocated to a user.  Your nodes are still in the commissioning state - commissioning needs to complete on the nodes during which they tell the MAAS server that commissioning is done and it switches state to "ready".

There are many reasons why commissioning is not completing, I suggest you have a look here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/maas/+faqs